# Mallocing Space for String Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, return-type, c-strings

I need help malloc space for a string array and then returning this value as a pointer.

How do I go about doing this? My code is:

```
char * strArray[*arrLen] = malloc(srcStrLen - numOfDelimsInStr + (numOfDelimsInStr + 1));
```

I populate string array with memcpy and manual '\0' adds. Then I return the value via:

```
return (char **) strArray;
```

The error and warning I get upon compile are:

```
answer03.c:48:3: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
   char * strArray[*arrLen] = malloc(srcStrLen - numOfDelimsInStr + (numOfDelimsInStr + 1));
   ^
answer03.c:68:3: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   return (char **) strArray;
   ^
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial for malloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, allocate memory for `strArray`.

Assuming, `arrLen` is an integral variable, not a pointer,

```
char** strArray = malloc(arrLen*sizeof(*strArray));
if ( strArray == NULL )
{
   // Deal with error condition
}
```

Then, allocate memory for each element of the array.

```
for ( i = 0; i < arrLen; ++i )
{
   strArray[i] = malloc(srcStrLen - numOfDelimsInStr + (numOfDelimsInStr + 1));
   if ( strArray[i] == NULL )
   {
      // Deal with error condition
   }
}
```

Then, return the array.

```
return strArray;
```